# Tuning the classification threshold in mlr

Tags: machine-learning, classification, threshold, mlr

I am training a Naive Bayes model using the mlr package.

I would like to tune the threshold (and *only* the threshold) for the classification. The [tutorial](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/over_and_undersampling.html#tuning-the-probability-threshold) provides an example for doing this while also doing additional hyperparameter tuning in a nested CV-setting. *I actually do not want to tune any other (hyper)parameter while finding the optimal threshold value.*

Based on the discussion [here](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr/issues/856)  I set up a makeTuneWrapper() object and set another parameter (laplace) to a fixed value (1) and subsequently run resample() in a nested CV-setting.

```
nbayes.lrn <- makeLearner("classif.naiveBayes", predict.type = "prob")
nbayes.lrn

nbayes.pst <- makeParamSet(makeDiscreteParam("laplace", value = 1))
nbayes.tcg <- makeTuneControlGrid(tune.threshold = TRUE)
# Inner 
rsmp.cv5.desc<-makeResampleDesc("CV", iters=5, stratify=TRUE)
nbayes.lrn<- makeTuneWrapper(nbayes.lrn, par.set=nbayes.pst, control=nbayes.tcg, resampling=rsmp.cv5.desc, measures=tpr) 
# Outer 
rsmp.cv10.desc<-makeResampleDesc("CV", iters=10, stratify=TRUE)
nbayes.res<-resample(nbayes.lrn, beispiel3.tsk, resampling= rsmp.cv10.desc, measures=list(tpr,ppv), extract=getTuneResult)

print(nbayes.res$extract)
```

Setting up a resampling scheme for the inner loop in the nested CV seems superfluous. The internal call to [tuneThreshold()](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/reference/tuneThreshold.html) apparently does a more thorough optimization anyhow. However, calling makeTuneWrapper() without a resampling scheme leads to an error message.

I have two specific **questions**:

1.) Is there a simpler way of tuning a threshold (and only the threshold)?

2.) Given the setup used above: how can I access the threshold values that were actually tested?

**EDIT:**

This would be a code example for tuning the threshold for different measures (accuraccy, sensitivity, precision) based on the answer by @Lars Kotthoff.

```
### Create fake data
y<-c(rep(0,500), rep(1,500))
x<-c(rep(0, 300), rep(1,200), rep(0,100), rep(1,400))
balanced.df<-data.frame(y=y, x=x)
balanced.df$y<-as.factor(balanced.df$y)
balanced.df$x<-as.factor(balanced.df$x)
balanced.tsk<-makeClassifTask(data=balanced.df, target="y",   positive="1")
summarizeColumns(balanced.tsk)

### TuneThreshold
logreg.lrn<-makeLearner("classif.logreg", predict.type="prob")
logreg.mod<-train(logreg.lrn, balanced.tsk)
logreg.preds<-predict(logreg.mod, balanced.tsk)
threshold_tpr<-tuneThreshold(logreg.preds, measure=list(tpr))
threshold_tpr
threshold_acc<-tuneThreshold(logreg.preds, measure=list(acc))
threshold_acc
threshold_ppv<-tuneThreshold(logreg.preds, measure=list(ppv))
threshold_ppv
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tuneThreshold()` directly:

```
require(mlr)

iris.model = train(makeLearner("classif.naiveBayes", predict.type = "prob"), iris.task)
iris.preds = predict(iris.model, iris.task)

res = tuneThreshold(iris.preds)
```

Unfortunately, you can't access the threshold values that were tested when using `tuneThreshold()`. You could however treat the threshold value as a "normal" hyperparameter and use any of the tuning methods in mlr. This would allow you to get the values and corresponding performance.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful!

Comment: Not sure how this would work treating the threshold as a normal hyperparameter, though. The threshold is not listed as a tunable parameter for learners such as Naive Bayes or logistic regression. Since the result of tuneThreshold() uses "th" for threshold I simply tried that.'makeParamSet(makeDiscreteParam("th", values=seq(from=0.05, to=0.95, by=0.05)))' But adopting the normal procedure from the tutorial results in an error when calling tuneParams() with 'tuneParams("classif.logreg", task=balanced.tsk, resampling=rsmp.holdout.desc, par.set=param_set, control=tune_ctrl_grid)'.

Comment: You may have to wrap your learner in a "learner" that allows you to set the threshold as a parameter. Unfortunately, this isn't straightforward.

Comment: Hi @LarsKotthoff, thank you for posting. I have a question regarding `tuneThreshold` here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/446362/127926. It's about the difference between tuning it in tandem with learner parameters via `makeTuneControlRandom(..., tune.threshold = TRUE)` vs using it directly via `tuneThreshold(r$pred)`. Would it please be possible to have a look at it?